# In 7 Wonders, does getting a VP for all yellow cards include the card mentioning it?

Tags: 7-wonders

In 7 wonders, there is a yellow card whose icons say "get a VP for each yellow card I have played".   If I already have 3 yellow cards in play, is my total VP from yellow cards 3 or 4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the last page of the rules, it clarifies that the card does count itself, so you would get 4 VPs.

Comment: Right, I meant game board instead of cards in hands.